# Is there a managed API for finding a window's handle by window title?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
private Bitmap getScreenshotOfWindow(String windowTitle) {
    RECT win32Rect;
    HandleRef handle = new HandleRef(this, Handle);

    if (!GetWindowRect(handle, out win32Rect)) {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Error: unable to get window boundaries.");
        return null;
    }

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.X = win32Rect.Left;
    bounds.Y = win32Rect.Top;
    bounds.Width = win32Rect.Right - win32Rect.Left + 1;
    bounds.Height = win32Rect.Bottom - win32Rect.Top + 1;

    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)) {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    return screenshot;
}
```

Is there any way to create a `HandleRef` object that depends on the string `windowTitle` using managed API?

EDIT: Here is the code I ended up with:

```
private Bitmap getScreenshotOfWindow(String windowTitle) {
    RECT win32Rect;
    IntPtr handle = getWindowHandle(windowTitle);

    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero) {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Error: Unable to find window.");
        return null;
    }

    if (!GetWindowRect(handle, out win32Rect)) {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Error: unable to get window boundaries.");
        return null;
    }

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.X = win32Rect.Left;
    bounds.Y = win32Rect.Top;
    bounds.Width = win32Rect.Right - win32Rect.Left + 1;
    bounds.Height = win32Rect.Bottom - win32Rect.Top + 1;

    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)) {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    return screenshot;
}

private IntPtr getWindowHandle(string windowTitle) {
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses()) {
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle.Equals(windowTitle)) {
            return proc.MainWindowHandle;
        }
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Forms have an handle proeprty but if you don't have access to the form in your project you will have to use winapi from what I know. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need to wrap the FindWindow native API. It's easy; see Pinvoke.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] _procs = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().GetProcesses();
```

Will return all processes running on the local computer. You may iterate through them.

Main window title will be present on the `Process.MainWindowTitle` property.

[Process.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be the bit you're interested about.